# C++ Armadillo Generate Indices uvec of a given vec or matrix without looping it

Tags: c++, indexing, armadillo

Hellos guys,

My question might be obvious but i didn't find answers on other posts or Armadillo Doc.

I would like to create a vector B(arma::uvec in my case), with **every index** of a given vector A. So the needed elements are (0:A.n_elem-1). I could loop it, but I need to optimize time at its best, so I just want to know if I can generate it **without looping it**. Last point, I would like to avoid C++ 11.

Thank you for your time.

EDIT 1 : 
I did use find_finite(X), to generate my indices vec, because my datas are all finite, i still don't know the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite understand `with every index of a given vector A`, but if you need `B` to contain `0:A.n_elem-1`, you can do:

```
vec B = regspace<vec>(0, A.n_elem-1)
```

Above code is equivalent to `B = 0:length(A)-1`, in MATLAB.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't quite clear, but that's exactly what i wanted.