# C++ Armadillo: arrays of indices from 2D-matrix

Tags: c++, armadillo

I come from Python. I have a linear algebra problem to treat in C++, and I chose to use Armadillo to do so, as it advertises itself as being MATLAB-like, thus SciPy-like.

I'm looking for a way to populate two matrices, one with the rows, one with the columns of a 2D-matrix of given shape (in Python, that would be numpy.indices).

For instance, if I have a 4 rows/3 columns matrix shape, what I want is to build a row matrix:

```
0 0 0
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
```

and a column matrix:

```
0 1 2
0 1 2
0 1 2
0 1 2
```

in order to do some calculations afterwards.

It is similar to [C++ Armadillo Generate Indices uvec of a given vec or matrix without looping it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43869366/c-armadillo-generate-indices-uvec-of-a-given-vec-or-matrix-without-looping-it) but with a matrix instead of a 1D-vector.

Is there a way to do so without too much looping? I know about linspace to populate a vector, but I'd prefer not to loop over a a bunch of vectors to merge them in a matrix. I am just starting with Armadillo, and I am not really aware of its capabilities yet (basically, I just have matrices products and inversion to do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Aubergine. The ***armadillo*** library is very useful for scientific computing and easy to pick up. I would encourage to get family with its documentation page [armadillo documentation](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#example_prog)

Concerning your particular problem, here is a solution I am proposing:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<armadillo>

using namespace std;
using namespace arma;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // Create two matrices A and B of shape 4x3 filled with zeros
    imat A = zeros<imat>(4, 3);
    imat B = zeros<imat>(4, 3);

    // Fill each row
    for(int i=0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        A.row(i) = i * ones<ivec>(3).t();  // 
    }

    // Fill each column
    for(int i=0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        B.col(i) = i * ones<ivec>(4);
    }
    cout << "A = \n" << A << endl;
    cout << "B = \n" << B << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The compilation goes like this on my computers (Mac OSX and Ubuntu):

```
g++ -std=c++11 -O2 `pkg-config --cflags --libs armadillo` testArmadillo.cpp -o a.out
```

Then, we can run the executable simply by typing:

```
./a.out
```

and the output is as follows:

```
A =
    0        0        0
    1        1        1
    2        2        2
    3        3        3

B =
    0        1        2
    0        1        2
    0        1        2
    0        1        2
```

For more information about ***imat***, ***ivec***, see [imat](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Mat) and [ivec](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Col)

Comment: Looping it is then! I had a glance at the doc, but I also have a lot to catch up in standard C++. I used umat instead of imat as I only need positive integers; works like a charm. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

While the answer given does generate the requested matrices the OP asked for a solution not using loops. This answer uses regspace and repmat and is perhaps conceptually simpler:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>

using namespace std;
using namespace arma;

int main (int argc, char const* argv[])
{
    ivec a_col = regspace<ivec>(0, 3);
    imat A = repmat(a_col, 1, 3);

    irowvec b_row = regspace<irowvec>(0,2);
    imat B = repmat(b_row, 4, 1);

    cout << A << endl;
    cout << B << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I have to confess that I'm a little new to armadillo so I won't promise that this is fast or follows best practices, but I think it's probably closest to equivalent SciPy code.

Comment: Using `auto` with armadillo objects can lead to problems. Armadillo's [FAQ page](http://arma.sourceforge.net/faq.html#features) has more details.

Comment: @hbrerkere I just recently discovered this. Thanks for the clarification, I'll change it. =)